# Modern Themes Not Visible in the Gear Menu (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, custom, theme

I have just inherited a redesign project from a previous employee. I've never used SharePoint before, but I've done loads of reading and seen many YouTube videos and I've been able to create a custom theme and add it via PowerShell.

I can't see the new theme because it appears the old themes are still active, but yet we're using modern templates. I'm really confused on how to get on with this SharePoint Online instance.

Here's what I see when I click the gear icon:

[image: Classic Themes?]

Here's what I want to see:

[image]

I assume the last guy changed a setting, but I'm not sure where to look. Most of the pages have the "on page" editing where you can do colored backgrounds and it's modern, but I can't see modern themes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The themes and screens you have displayed are only for the Classic UI. (I.e. they only work with Master Pages.)

Modern UI themes really have nothing in common with Classic themes.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-json-schema

Answer (score 0):

Could you please offer a screenshot about your modern page when you click Gear Menu?

Per my test, in modern team site, when i click Gear Menu->Change the look->Theme->I will get the theme like the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My screenshots in the orignal post show what I see. When I click the gear menu, I see the same menu as in your screenshot, but when I click "Change the look" it goes to the old theme page.